# I get unexpected token "eos" using the following template with jade?

Tags: pug

This template:

```
h1 Editing #{product.name}
form(action='/products/'+product.id, method='POST')
  p
    label(for='product_name')
      Name:
    input(type='text', id='product_name', name='product[name]', value=product.name)
  p
    label(for='product_description')
      Description:
    input(id='product_name', name='product[description]')= product.description
  p
    input(type='submit')
```

gives me this error:

```
Error: /home/alex/apps/express2/views/products/edit.jade:10
    8|       Description:
    9|   p
  > 10| 

unexpected token "eos"
    at Object.parseExpr (/home/alex/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:222:15)
    at Object.block (/home/alex/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:521:25)
    at Object.parseTag (/home/alex/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:612:26)
    at Object.parseExpr (/home/alex/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:188:21)
    at Object.block (/home/alex/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:521:25)
    at Object.parseTag (/home/alex/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:612:26)
    at Object.parseExpr (/home/alex/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:188:21)
    at Object.parse (/home/alex/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:129:25)
    at parse (/home/alex/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:101:62)
    at Object.compile (/home/alex/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:148:9)
```

Any suggestions to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

escape colon after Name and Description
so it would be
Name\: and Description\:

It seems that colon has a special meaning and is parsed by jade